# How to disable Tab key on particular column index of Datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can Anybody please tell me how to disable Tab key only on a particular column index of datagridview ?

I have tried

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
{
   e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

but it didn't worked.

i want something like

```
if(e.ColumnIndex==6)
{
   //disable tab key
}
```

Comment: this is the perfect solution for your case
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71000393/3892975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook up `KeyDown` event of `DataGridView` and see if the selected cell belongs to column 6. If so eat the key.

```
void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab &&
        dataGridView1.SelectedCells
                     .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                     .Any(x => x.ColumnIndex == 6))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Now that's clear for me. `KeyDown` won't fire in editing mode because editing control will get those events. One way to do is override `ProcessCmdKey` in form or the usercontrol where `DataGridView` lives.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Tab &&
        dataGridView1.EditingControl != null &&
        msg.HWnd == dataGridView1.EditingControl.Handle  &&
        dataGridView1.SelectedCells
            .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
            .Any(x => x.ColumnIndex == 6))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply sriram . but could you tell me how do i disable the tab key by code not by using keydown event?

Comment: No, you can't . You need to listen to event or some kind of overridden method, then suppress the key. *No two ways about it*. Am not sure what do you meant by *how do i disable the tab key by code*? What's wrong with events?

Comment: actually the column for which i am firing the keydown event is in edit mode and i googled that the keydown event doesn't get fired when the cell is in edit mode..so i was wondering that i could disable it from dataGridView1_CellEnterEvent or something similar to that..any suggestions?

Comment: @user1511434 Updated my answer. See if that helps. If not feel free to comment.